# PyCharm / git: "not a valid object name"

Tags: git

I've made a "big" commit + push of a lot of static files.
But one problem appeared: 2 folders, `select2` and `vue`, containing `dist` folders, were not correctly "pushed".

Here's what `select2` contains:

[image: select2 content]

And when I watch my "log" in the "Version Control" tab, I see this:

[image: Push picture]

If I double-click on either `select2` or `vue` I get a window with a message "`fatal: Not a valid object name blablablabla:static/vendors/select2`" or "`fatal: Not a valid object name blablablabla:static/vendors/vue`"

I would just like to *remove* those problems and be able to push those folders. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do this:

```
git rm --cached static/vendors/vue
git rm --cached static/vendors/select2
```

And then to re-add the folders. Then it worked.